# How to write unit-test for http-post inside an observable in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, observable, angular7, karma-runner

I have web.service.ts, and I want to write a unit-test for this. But I am stuck in one method.

```
updateClientConfiguration(id, data){

   var res = this.http.post<any> 
   (`${this.configUrl}/${this.helper.getNodeIP()}/clients/${id}`,data);  //1

    res.subscribe(result => {                                        //2
      if(data.type == "aws")
      {
        console.log("Updating AWS UI");
      }
      else if(data.type == "azure")
      {
        console.log("Updating AZURE UI");
        data[data.type].sasToken = tmpData;
      }
      else if(data.type == "local_lake")
      {
        console.log("Updating LOCAL_LAKE UI");
      }
    });

    return res;
  }
```

I want to get 100% coverage for this code, just by checking console messages in each 'if' block. How to test inside the res.subscribe{} block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Mock the http.post and call the function.

```
let httpClient : HttpClient;
httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
spyOn(httpClient,"post").and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse()));
service.updateClientConfiguration(data.clientId,data).subscribe(response => {     
    expect(consoleSpy.calledWith(consoleMsg)).toBe(true);
 });
```